# Having trouble using unless current_page? to hide a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to hide this button from all the show pages of the `Rooms` model.  I have an array of the rooms `id` stored in `@extra` but whenever I try to use `current_page?(room_path(@extra))` it doesn't work, but when I specify the id, for example, `current_page?(room_path(6))` it works and hides the button.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<% unless current_page?(controller: 'rooms') || current_page?(room_path(@extra))%>

   <button onclick="myFunction()" class="button btn btn-light bg-white rounded-pill shadow-sm px-4 mb-4" 
   style="vertical-align:middle">
   <span>
      <small class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold"> Nav-bar Toggle</small>
   </span>
</button>

      <% end %>
```

routes/rb

```
require 'sidekiq/web'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :messages
  resources :rooms
  # Routing for budget section
  resources :budgets do
    resources :groups do
      resources :categories
    end
  end

  resources :posts do 
    resources :likes
    resources :comments
  end
  
  resources :socials
  resources :mentions, only: [:index]
  resources :mentioned_posts, only: [:index]
  resources :follows
  resources :followers, only: [:index]
  resources :followings, only: [:index]


  resources :accounts
  resources :goals
  resources :retirements
  get '/users', to: 'users#index'
  get '/user/:id', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
  resources :calculate_debts
  
  get '/privacy', to: 'home#privacy'
  get '/terms', to: 'home#terms'
    authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
      mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
    end


  resources :notifications, only: [:index]
  resources :announcements, only: [:index]
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  root to: 'home#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: I believe `room_path` is expecting an integer and not an array. Why are you passing an array to this?

Comment: When  try to run it the normal way ```<% unless current_page?(controller: 'rooms', action: 'show') %>``` I get this error ```No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"rooms"}```

Comment: I only get this error when I leave the ```rooms``` index page or show page, and that's why I thought of storing the values in an array since the other method didn't work

Comment: Possible to share your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: I just added it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided in the comments. The `show` path needs an id to be complete. You can check it with,

```
current_page?(controller: 'rooms', action: 'show', id: room_id)
```

instead of

```
current_page?(controller: 'rooms', action: 'show')
```

---

If you want to check against a particular room id, you can use

```
current_page?(controller: 'rooms', action: 'show', id: room_id)
```

If you want to check just the controller and action, irrespective of the room id, you'll have to use another strategy. You can use,

```
if params[:controller] == :rooms && params[:action] == :show
```

or match against a regex

```
if request.fullpath =~ /\/rooms\/\d+/
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to run that ```undefined local variable or method `room_id' for #<#<Class:0x00007f70418f3938>:0x00007f70418f1480>
Did you mean?  dom_id``` What is the ```id: room_id``` suppose to do?

Comment: `room_id` was just an example I gave. You'll need to replace this with the id of the room you are looking for.